# Access to embed resource from DLL in Web Sites

Tags: vb.net, web, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

We have a MyDLL.dll file that contains multiple embedded images. This DLL offers a method to get any of these images by doing :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyDLL." & imageName)
```

If this library is used in a .NET application, it works fine. If we call

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

we get 340 items. However, if we use the same DLL in a Web site (by adding it in the "bin" folder), the same method always returns Nothing, and the GetManifestResourceNames() method returns no items.

I don't know much about assemblies and how they are loaded, so how could I add my DLL in the resources names? Or at least how could I make it work?

Thank you.

Yvon

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, instead of using a Web Site projet, I used an ASP.NET Web Forms Application project. That did the trick!